# autoload config file into a variable

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

When we return an array of configs, we can include it into a variable in a separate file like:

```
a.php

return   array(
'host' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'pass' => 'password',
'database' => 'db'
);
```

and

```
B.php

$config = include(a.php)
```

is it possible to load it via composer files and get the config array in b.php by including the composer autoload file?

```
"autoload": {
"classmap": ["d.class.php"],
"files": [
"a.php",
"c.php"
]
},
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Composer includes files within a function which limits the scope of variable from included files:

See ClassLoader.php from composer:

```
/**
 * Scope isolated include.
 *
 * Prevents access to $this/self from included files.
 *
 * @param  string $file
 * @return void
 * @private
 */
function includeFile($file)
{
    include $file;
}
```